# Copy Excel worksheet formatting using R

Tags: r, excel

How can one copy all formatting (colors, number formats, column widths, conditional formatting, etc.) and, possibly, pane freezing from an *Excel* worksheet and paste it into other worksheets using **R**?

E.g., how to copy styles from sheet "A", to sheets "B" and "C" in this file: [CopyStyles.xlsx](https://www.dropbox.com/s/v8uzwjvdv1af8q1/CopyStyles.xlsx?dl=1)

Comment: Probably the `getStyles` and `replaceStyle` functions of the `openxlsx`-package could be what you are looking for.

Comment: I added file which could be used for example. Could you provide with an example how to use the functions in this case?

Comment: Little research effort demonstrated.

Answer (score 1):

Here you go:

```
require(XLConnect)
file.copy(from ="r-xlsx-report-example.xlsx", to= "r-xlsx-report-example3.xlsx" ) ## copy
wb <- loadWorkbook("r-xlsx-report-example3.xlsx") ## read
imena <- getSheets(wb) #sheetsname
df <-  readWorksheet(wb, 
                     sheet = 1
                     ,startRow = 3)
df$Sepal.Length[df$Sepal.Length < 6] <- "my new data"  #change

writeWorksheetToFile("r-xlsx-report-example3.xlsx",df, sheet = imena[1],styleAction = XLC$STYLE_ACTION.NONE,header=T,startRow=3)
saveWorkbook(wb,"r-xlsx-report-example3.xlsx") ## save
```